# Visualising geospatial .tiff images with Rasterio

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geospatial, rasterio, earthpy

I am trying to visualise a .tiff image in Jupiter Notebook using Rasterio. I am a Junior Data Scientist for an AgriTech company and we just got access to 8 data layers (NDVI etc.) for two farms in .tiff format.

Here is the metadata for one image:

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': -125125.0, 'width': 72, 'height': 87, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32734), 'transform': Affine(20.0, 0.0, 364480.0,
       0.0, -20.0, 6292100.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'lzw', 'interleave': 'band'}
```

When I run the following:

```
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

pic = rasterio.open('/content20180109_biow_Meerlust.tif','r',driver='GTiff',width=72,
      height=87,count=1, nodata=-125125.0)

show(pic,with_bounds=False)
```

I get a very pixelated image:

[image: test image]

How do I visualise the image without it being so pixelated? My knowledge of the array adjustments behind these .tiff images is limited as I just started in the Agronomics field. Open to any suggestions.

My aim is to create a web app using Streamlit where I can overlay these images and create a short video of how the layers change over time.

Answer (score 2):

here are a couple solutions that might help visualize multiple-band rasters with clarity. In both examples, `raster` is a [`rasterio.DatasetReader`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html) with multiple bands ([indexed at 1](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading.html)).

**1. Single Image**

To view all layers in a single 2D plane, the bands have to be concatenated:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bands = []
for i in range(raster.count):
    bands.append(raster.read(i+1, out_dtype=np.intc))

plt.title("Full Color Raster")
plt.imshow(np.array(bands))
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, because of limitations from pyplot's [`imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function, this method only works with a few layers (traditionally RGB). Feel free to use datatypes other than `np.intc`.

**2. Visualize Layers Separately**

The [`earthpy.plot`](https://earthpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/earthpy.plot.html) module has several clean options for visualizing raster layers, including the convenient [`plot_bands()`](https://earthpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery_vignettes/plot_bands_functionality.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import earthpy.plot as ep

bands = []

# Read the raster's bands to an array
for i in range(raster.count):
    bands.append(raster.read((i+1), out_dtype=raster.dtypes[i]))

# Convert to an iterable np.ndarray and plot in a 3-column grid
ep.plot_bands(np.array(bands), cols=3)
```

Really hope this helps! **This is my first Stack Overflow response**, so let me know if there's anything critical I omitted.